# Typing dynamic text into a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to display text on a screen as a user types it, with an underscore cursor showing after the text.  The best way I can describe what I'm trying to do is a similar look to using the command line.

What is the best way to do this? I haven't been able to get it to work using a simple text input with css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something to get you started with jQuery.

```
$('input').on('input', function(e){
    $('div').empty().text($(this).val());
});
```

Edit: blinking underscore can be done with CSS

```
div:after{
   content:"_";
   opacity:0;
   animation:blink .500s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blink{
   from{opacity:0;}
   to{opacity:1;}
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that he wants a blinking underscore cursor.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `empty()` - `text()` will truncate it automatically.

Comment: Nice edit. I like the CSS solution. I was going to post a JS solution.

Comment: I typically like to ensure the attribute is empty.  I've done code where the text just appends to the current content which was not desired.

Answer (score 0):

The best way? Read the content on every `keyup` and then inject it into a destination container to show it to the user. Easy.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/VDd6C/8/

Show us your code. We'll help.

Comment: The problem with this is that he wants a blinking underscore cursor.

Answer (score 0):

A basic one, try this (tested in Chrome and FF)

[image: Demo here]

**[Play it here](http://jsfiddle.net/sxzak0j6/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span contenteditable="true">Enter your input: </span><span class="blink">_</span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $('.blink').toggle();
}, 450);
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: courier;
}
span {
 border: none;
}
div {
     max-width: 200px;   
}
div:focus, span:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```